# how to call a method declared inside the class_methods do of a module in ruby?

Tags: ruby

fileA.rb

```
module A 
    def self.extended(base)
    base.extend(ActiveSupport::Concern)
  end
end
```

fileB.rb

```
module B extend A
 included do ...
  ...
 end
 class_methods do 
  ...
   def function1(&block)
    ...
    ...
   end

   def function2(a: nil,b: nil)
     function1 do |some_name|
     ... 
     //do some thing by the combination of all//
     ...
   end
 end
 def function3
   self.class.function2(a: x, b: y) // This call is not doing any execution   
            // of the code snippets inside the function 2 above
 end
```

How can I call the function 2, which is present inside the class_methods do of the module B by the function3 which is called from another class that inherited the module B.

I tried as above and it failed in the next line of my code, it was like the function2 just got skipped, none of the stuffs inside the function 2 got executed, really weird. Am I missing something kindly give some help over here please.

I am in another class.

fileD.rb
    class D << class YY
      include B
       function3  // Calling the method function3 here
       /// The above call is reaching the expected place
    end

Comment: Why did you include the WATIR tag here?

Comment: Actually we are writing the test script, using watir that is why included that over there.

Comment: But there is nothing related to WATIR here, add Watir when question is related to WATIR.

Comment: There's some code formatting issues here, too. Use `#` for comments in Ruby.

Comment: Acutally I put that for showing that as a comment, In my real code it is '#' only.